# mouseover/mouseout jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have a mouseover and mouseout, where I am hiding/showing some div's on the mouseover then reverse the hide/show on mouse out.  It works, but if i quickly move my mouse over the Div i'm mousing over to reveal the divs, it will go back and forth about 3 times, showing and hiding.  What am I missing?

```
$("TABLE.tbl-graphs DIV.util").mouseover(
    function(){
        $("DIV.pic-container, DIV.util-info").hide("slow");
        $("DIV.util-description").show("slow");
    });
$("TABLE.tbl-graphs DIV.util").mouseout(
    function(){
        $("DIV.pic-container, DIV.util-info").show("slow");
        $("DIV.util-description").hide("slow");
    });
```

Comment: Consider using `hover()` or at least chaining your events `.mouseover().mouseout();` so you don't do process the selector twice. Hmz seems like you might want [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) before calling `.show()` or `.hide()`. You probably also want to use [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) - the difference is in the event bubbling.

Try this on for size:

```
var $divs = $("div.pic-container, div.util-info, div.util-description");

$("table.tbl-graphs div.util").live('mouseenter mouseleave'
function() {
    $divs.stop().toggle("slow");
});
```

Note that the `<div>`s to show/hide need to be in the correct initial state for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for dequeue: http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/

This doesn't allowed queued events (e.g hovering over the div and have it fade in and out three times, only once)

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do solve this problem is with a simple flag, so if it's currently doing something it ignores the mouse request, for instance

```
if(flag) return;
flag = true
```

and then add a callback of flag = false to your functions

Answer (score 0):

Try .stop(true, true) to prevent animation queing.
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

You might also want to check out .hover(handlerIn, handlerOut). http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1